# Squid reverse proxy redirect / rewrite HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: reverse-proxy, https, squid

My Squid Reverse Proxy only accepts HTTPS requests. What is a short way to redirect/rewrite a HTTP-request to https? 
So if the user visits `http://foo.server.com` he should be automatically redirected to `https://foo.server.com`

Answer (score 4):

One way is to get the origin server to do the redirect, but it seems more efficient to get Squid to do it. There are a couple of approaches, but using deny_info seems the easiest.

In the squid.conf configuration file:

```
acl PORT80 myport 80
acl MYSITE dstdomain foo.server.com
http_access deny PORT80 MYSITE
deny_info 301:https://foo.server.com%R MYSITE
```

At first glance, the http_access statement just denies access to the HTTP version of your site. However due to the deny_info statement Squid will redirect users to an alternative site (in this case the HTTPS version) rather than simply giving an access-denied message.

The `%R` tag causes the request URL path to be included in the redirect, so that if users try to visit `http://foo.server.com/bar` then they'll get directed to `https://foo.server.com/bar`, rather than just `https://foo.server.com`.

The full list of URL format tags is available in the Squid documentation: http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/deny_info/

The order of the acl statements is important because Squid only remembers the last `http_access deny` and looks for the `deny_info` to match that acl.

Comment: Is there a way for Squid to automatically upgrade the connection to https and forward it, so the client doesn't know or care that http is blocked?